# In ConTeXt: how to change the hsize locally?

Tags: context

In ConTeXt, I have text that is say 5cm wide. Once in a while I'd like to have a table or an image that sticks out of the right margin and is for example 10 cm wide. My idea is to have something like `\startnarrower`, just the opposite way. So what is the best approach to that? I have not specified my layout yet, so I am open to any clean solution.

Comment: Patrick, don't you mean `\startnarrower` ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I have changed it in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the [details manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/details.pdf) has lots of ideas on how to "bleed" an image to margins. Also see [pack-box.mkiv](http://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/pack-box.mkiv) for examples (search for bleed).

You can also use

```
\startnarrower[-left]
\stopnarrower
```

for text.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do now:

```
\setuplayout [
    backspace=2cm,
    width=10cm,
    height=20cm,
    rightmargin=10cm,
    ]

\showframe
\starttext

\definestartstop
  [big]
  [before={\setupnarrower[right=-4cm]\startnarrower[right]},
   after={\stopnarrower}]


\startbig
\externalfigure[cow][width=\localhsize]
\stopbig

\input tufte

\stoptext
```

It's exactly what I want. Thanks Aditya and Taco!

Comment: Careful! `\definestartstop[big]` also defines a macro `\big`, which overwrites the math macro `\big`.

Comment: That's true. I'll think of another name.